# How to summarize data by several groups (R)

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

And I want to get this, that is, a single row per Group, with a column for the % of As in all the ID_1_Subgroup for each Group, together with the sum of ValueSubgroup, for each group too):

[image]

Can someone help? I have seen other issues (like this: [Summarizing by group and subgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987228/summarizing-by-group-and-subgroup)) which are similar but not for R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(Group) %>%
     summarise(PercA = mean(id_1_Subgroup == "A"),
               SumOfValueSubgroup = sum(ValueSubgroup))
```