# Crystal reports foreach loop in the formula field

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

Please help me to get the count of profile Ids foreach category in crystal report formula field.

I need to display Like : 2 people registered for Electrical Category

This my Sql Query result in the report.

```
ProID    CATID      Description
1            2           Inspection
1            4           Fabric Maintenance
1            6           Electrical
1           10           General Qualifications
3            6           Electrical
3           10           General Qualifications
4            1           QA /QC Vendor Inspection
6            1           QA /QC Vendor Inspection
11           1           QA /QC Vendor Inspection
12           1           QA /QC Vendor Inspection
12           2           Inspection
12           3           Coatings Inspection
12          10           General Qualifications
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you used group by on description in crystal report

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a new group for category and you can use a sum(,) to solve the above requirement

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080918181105AAsqVoC
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/9da5e3fb-a2ea-4337-b098-33f2b142fd0c/
[Conditional group SUM in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545883/conditional-group-sum-in-crystal-reports)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying to do something stupid in the formulas. Now I use count of profileIds for each category the in Group section and also inserted a bar chart as well. Thanks for saving my hours.