# Translating this formula to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

I have this formula in one of the report's fields:

```
Sum ({@MarketValue}, {IA.AS_AT_DATE}, "daily")
```

But I'm not sure what is the intent here or what "daily" does in this case.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is this the actual full formula and it's working?

Comment: @FutbolFan The report runs, but can't say if it's spewing the correct numbers, I just opened it to translate it to an SQL query.

Comment: Okay, couple of things that you may notice right away: `IA.AS_AT_DATE`  is probably a date field. The question should be here: why are you summing up a date field? Also, `sum` function is being used with a string. Check this out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4752956/1821329

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to:

http://scn.sap.com/thread/910242

```
Sum (fld, condFld, cond)
```

> fld is any valid database or formula field that can be evaluated by the function.
>   condFld is a field used to group the values in fld by.
>   cond is a String indicating the type of grouping for condFld. You only specify this argument when condFld is a Date, Time, DateTime or Boolean field. For more information on the valid strings for this argument, see Conditions for summary functions.

would mean:

sum the `@MarketValue` grouped by `day` (`daily` grouping on the `{IA.AS_AT_DATE}`.

Comment: I don't understand this though. How can one group 50443.12, for example "by day" ?

Comment: is your `AS_AT_DATE` not a date? why is it called a date? :O  Though in sql server `select convert(datetime, 50443.12)` does convert to the date `2038-02-09 2:52:48`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is very poor written. Think somebody ment for the agg column to be called as 'daily'

Comment: this should be a comment.